# preg_replace itereation

Tags: php, regex

This is how my code looks like:

```
$x = '<p>This is a <a href="1.php?src=123">first</a> paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a <a href="2.php?id=987">second</a> pararaph.</p>
<p>This is a <a href="3.php?reL=666">third</a> paragraph'</p>;
```

I would like to replace all these links and add a number. A number of iteration. In the first link, it should add `&i=1`, in second `&i=2`, third `&i=3`, fourth `&i=4`, etc.

**Edit**: I've tried to match all `a` tags and get them to the array:

```
$input = '<p><a href="1.php?src=123">x</a></p> <p><a href="2.php?id=987">y</a></p> <p><a href="3.php?rel=666">third</a></p>';
$output = [];
preg_match("/href=\"(.*)\"/", $input, $output);
print_r($output);
```

However, it returns an array with two elements, and at phpliveregex.com it's a bit different.

Comment: Give it a shot and  if you need help then come back with a question :~)

Comment: Well okay. I've tried to match all "a" tags and get them to the array:

`$input = '<p><a href="1.php?src=123">x</a></p> <p><a href="2.php?id=987">y</a></p> <p><a href="3.php?rel=666">third</a></p>';

$output = [];

preg_match("/href=\"(.*)\"/", $input, $output);
print_r($output);`

However, it returns an array with two elements, and at http://www.phpliveregex.com/ it's a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there.

```
$input = '<p><a href="1.php?src=123">x</a></p> <p><a href="2.php?id=987">y</a></p> <p><a href="3.php?rel=666">third</a></p>';
$output = [];
preg_match_all("/href=\"(.*?)\"/", $input, $output);
print_r($output);
```

There were two problems:

- `preg_match` only matches the first occurrence; use `preg_match_all` instead
- make your regex **lazy** by adding a question mark: `(.*?)` - it should match as short a string as possible (i.e. stop at the first `"` it finds instead of the last)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I was so close..